# Sparkly particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm currently working on a number of almost ethereal object, and I'd like them to emit a number of sparkly, glittery particles (almost like pixie dust, best example I can think of). I'd like them to have a bit of some "star" lines coming from them—this perhaps could be achieved by making the particles brighter in certain areas?

Sort of a combination of what appears in these two images:

[image]

[image]

How exactly would I go about doing this? Billboards, or object particles, what sorts of materials, etc.?

(Note: this should work with the glare node on "fog glow")

Comment: Please provide image/animation example.

Comment: Added reference images.

Comment: Edited to provide differences from linked question.

Comment: Utilize chosen method from provided link and add to it this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97873/separate-compositor-glare Glare Node > Streaks in Compositing. I'm sure there are plenty of resources about it.

Comment: I accidentally referred to the "bloom node" in my description. I fixed and clarified what I meant.

Comment: Those methods are working with Fog Glow. My answer is even using it on the gifs there.